# how to compile and run two different java programs with instances of one in another which are in different directories?

Tags: java, classpath

my first java program is

```
import java.io.*;
class pgm10a
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        pgm10b b=new pgm10b();
        b.display();
    }
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("A class");
    }
}
```

it is saved in C:\NNK\pack1
the second program is

```
import java.io.*;
class pgm10b
{
    void pgm10b()
    {
        pgm10a a=new pgm10a();
        a.display();
    }
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Class B");
    }
}
```

it is in C:\NNK\pack2
I want to run pgm10a but it keeps showing pgm10b not found exception. i have set the class path and compiled for both and both are compiled successfully. but when i try to run them it shows pgm10b not found.

[image]

Comment: @JonnyHenly i don't understand...include as in import the class. can you give a example

Comment: If they're in the same package they shouldn't *be* in different directories.

Comment: @EJP they are not in same package.

Comment: Then you haven't posted enough of the code for a solution to be provided. The answer depends on the package names in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [syntax for the `java` command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> **java** [*options*] *classname* [*args*]

Anything after the class name is not an option to the **java** command—it is simply passed as is, in a String array, to the program’s `main` method.

You can solve your problem by changing your final command from this:

```
java pgm10a -cp C:\NNK\pack2
```

to this:

```
java -cp .;C:\NNK\pack2 pgm10a
```

The classpath is a sequence of directories, separated by `;` when running in Windows (`:` on other operating systems), which tell the java command where to find compiled classes.  If you only specify `C:\NNK\pack2`, Java will only be able to see classes in that directory.  The period (`.`) refers to the current directory, so the above classpath is pointing to both the current directory (which contains pgm10a) and the pack2 directory (which contains pgm10b).

Comment: it removed the class not found error. but gives a new error as `could not find or load main class pgm10a`. what is the problem now?? I know its beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: You need both directories in your classpath.  I’ve updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @VGR thanks it worked!!but can you explain what you have done, how adding just  .; solved the problem.

Comment: Explanation added to answer.